# Consecutively split an array by the next max value

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array (the elements can be floats also):

```
D = np.array([0,0,600,160,0,1200,1800,0,1800,900,900,300,1400,1500,320,0,0,250])
```

The goal is, starting from the beginning of the array, to find the max value (the *last* one if there are several equal ones) and cut the anterior part of the array. Then consecutively repeat this procedure till the end of the array. So, the expected result would be:

```
[[0,0,600,160,0,1200,1800,0,1800],
 [900,900,300,1400,1500],
 [320],
 [0,0,250]]
```

I managed to find the last max value:

```
D_rev = D[::-1]
last_max_index = len(D_rev) - np.argmax(D_rev) - 1
```

i.e. I can get the first subarray of the desired answer. And then I can use a loop to get the rest.

My question is, if there is a numpy way to do it without looping?

Comment: you output array is invalid (different lengths)

Comment: The result must not obligatory be a numpy array (I've edited the desired output). But your comment means that looping is unavoidable?

Comment: I don't get the logic. first you use 1800 to cut, then why don't you use 1500 as the next maximum? Why the second element of the answer is not [900,900, 300,1400,1500]?   Answering your last question `if there is a numpy way to do it without looping`? Yes, you can easily do this with recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can take the reverse cumulated max (see [`accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html)) of D to form groups, then split with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
D = np.array([0,0,600,160,0,1200,1800,0,1800,900,900,300,1400,1500,320,0,0,250])

groups = np.maximum.accumulate(D[::-1])[::-1]
# array([1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1500, 1500,
#       1500, 1500, 1500,  320,  250,  250,  250])

from itertools import groupby
out = [list(list(zip(*g))[0]) for _, g in groupby(zip(D, groups), lambda x: x[1])]

# [[0, 0, 600, 160, 0, 1200, 1800, 0, 1800],
#  [900, 900, 300, 1400, 1500],
#  [320],
#  [0, 0, 250]]
```